# python what's the element in []

Tags: python, list

I recently studied a python recursion function and found that the recursion stops when it uses element in []. So I made a simple test function, found that there is even no print out. So how can I understand the element in []? Why does the function stop when referring to element in []?

```
b=1
def simple():
    for i in []:
        print('i am here')
        return i+b
a = simple()
```

Comment: There are no elements in `[]`.  The body of that for-loop executes zero times.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `in` keyword has two purposes.

One use in as part of a `for` loop, which is written `for element in iterable`. This assigns each value from `iterable` to `element` on each pass through the loop body. This is how your example function is using `in` (though since the list you're looping over is empty, the loop never does anything).

The other way you can use `in` is as an operator. An expression like `x in y` tests if element `x` is present in container `y`. (There's also a negated version of the `in` operator, `not in`. The expression `x not in y` is exactly equivalent to `not (x in y)`.)  I suspect this is what your recursive code is doing. This would also not be useful to do with an empty list literal (since an empty list by definition doesn't contain anything), but I'm guessing the real recursive function is a bit more complicated.

As an example of both uses of `in`, here's a generator function that uses a set to filter out duplicate items from some other iterable. It has a `for` loop that has `in`, and it also uses `in` (well, technically `not in`) as an operator to test if the next value from the input iterator is contained in the `seen` set:

```
def unique(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:               # "in" used by for loop
        if item not in seen:            # "in" used here as an operator
            yield item
            seen.add(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function calls itself n-number of times, then returns a terminating value on the last recursion that backs out of the recursive stacks.

Example:
compute the factorial of a number:

```
def fact(n):
    # ex: 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
    # n == 0 is your terminating recursion
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    # else is your recursion call to fact(n-1)
    else:
        return n * fact(n-1)
```

In your example, there is no recursive call to simple() within the function, nor are there any element inside the empty list [] to step through, therefore your for loop never executed

Answer (score 0):

Its concerned about mechanism of 'for loop'.

Superficially, the iterator you want to travese (which is "[]" in you example) has a length of 0, so the body of the loop (which include "print" an so on) will not be executed.

Hope it helps.